# Need assitance with IF statement and JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to figure out how I can use an if statement to filter my JSON results on a page. Each recipe has its own category and I am trying to be able to filter the information based on type category type and other paramaters. I only included some code for people to get the idea but when I run this I get nothing. Here is my code:

```js
$.each(json, function(i, item) {
 if (item.recipeCategories == "fall") { 
       //show correct items in div
    }
});
```

```html
var json = 
    
[
   {   
    "recipeName":"Crispy Zucchini Fritte with Lemon Aioli",
    "recipeCategories":[
             "appetizers",
       "spring"
       ],
 },
    {   
    "recipeName":"Hummus Tahini",
    "recipeCategories":[
             "desserts",
       "fall"
       ],
 }
]
```

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: its in a JSON file

Comment: Fair enough. :-) But by the time you're doing what you describe above, it's not JSON anymore. It's been parsed into an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (item.recipeCategories == "fall") {
```

checks to see if `item.recipeCategories` is `==` to `"fall"`, but the `recipeCategories` in your array of objects is, itself, an array. You may want [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or in *really* modern JavaScript, [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)):

```
if (item.recipeCategories.indexOf("fall") !== -1) {
```

as of ES2016 (and can be shimmed):

```
if (item.recipeCategories.includes("fall")) {
```

Example:

```js
var json = [
    {
        "recipeName": "Crispy Zucchini Fritte with Lemon Aioli",
        "recipeCategories": ["appetizers", "spring"],
 },
    {
        "recipeName": "Hummus Tahini",
        "recipeCategories": ["desserts", "fall"],
    }
];
$.each(json, function(i, item) {
    if (item.recipeCategories.indexOf("fall") != -1) {
        $("<div>").text(item.recipeName).appendTo(document.body);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since recipeCategories is an array then you can use `indexOf`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

See this bin for usage: https://jsbin.com/xilarewafe/edit?html,js,output